# Understanding a simple circuit containing multiple op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-amplifier

I'm trying to learn electronics on my own. I got this circuit from an old audio amplifier device I had lying around. I'm trying to understand how it works. I have some questions about it. Could you help me?

1. This point has a DC Voltage of +6V, and it oscillates in the range of a few mV in response to Audio In. Then the DC offset gets removed by the directly next capacitor. Is all of this correct? What's the point of all of it?
2. If I short this capacitor, the amplifier stops working. Why? Current through Audio In is still flowing, right? Is the capacitor there to remove some DC offset?
3. I don't think I understand what exactly the op-amps are doing and how they do it. I assume the transistors simply take the heavy work of providing the current needed to drive the Speaker once the input signal is completely amplified.

**Edit:**

I have redrawn the schematic. Also, I think I found the explanations by experimenting in Falstad Simulator:

1. The DC Offset at the output of OA1 is slightly above +6V because of R2; C3 removes that offset. The output of OA1 oscillates by more than a few mV. The job of OA1 is to increase back the voltage of the input, since the input got lowered its voltage by the load it is put through.
2. Through AudioIn is the path of least resistance to ground for the output of OA1 to go through, so C1 is there to remove that DC offset.
3. Explained in the comments: "OA2 and OA3 are driving the two outputs to be opposite from each other, plus they reduce the effect of the class B outputs."

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbops4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The circuit looks incomplete to me. Op-amp mid rail biasing is missing a resistor.

Comment: Perhaps the explanation would be easy to find if the circuit diagram was drawn in the conventional way...

Comment: @Andyaka Do you mean another 20k resistor should be in the C section? I also think that. However, I have analyzed the circuit board several times and I don't think I'm missing any component. But I could still be wrong: I'll update all of this if I happen to find anything else.

Comment: You ought to show the power rails for the op-amp and mention what voltage they are at. Maybe the op-amps are running from +24 volts and 0 volts.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Sorry about that. I drew the diagram many times and thought this looked OK. I'll figure out what I need to do to make it better.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry about that. Each of the OP-Amps is running directly from the 12V source. I'll update the image.

Comment: Then you are definitely missing a resistor somewhere.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you so much for the patience. I added two more components which were located far away from the rest of the circuit and I thought were irrelevant. It is a double sided board with SMD components, and it's very hard to follow the paths when they go underneath other components. Also, I think I drew the input power to the OP-Amps correctly?

Comment: Regarding third question, I'd say the OPA's are driving the two outputs to be opposite from each other, plus they reduce the effect of the class B outputs.

Comment: @PeteW Seems like you are correct. Thank you for the comment! It was a huge help.

Comment: Glat to hear it. Just curious, what product was this circuit come out of?

Comment: @PeteW It is an iPod speaker system. Brand: Speler, Model: BIM-169. Looks very similar to [this](https://www.jbl.com/dw/image/v2/AAUJ_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-masterCatalog_Harman/default/dw66e12776/On-Stage-Micro-Black-without-iPod-(3D-View-on-White)-1605x1605px.png?sw=537&sfrm=png).

Answer (score 1):

A more conventional/understandable way of drawing the circuit diagram.

[image: Amplifier circuit diagram]